# HTML Anchor Tag With Italic Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some html.

```
<a href="#">
   <i class="some-bg" />
   Some Text
</a>
```

And some Javascript.

```
$("a").bind("touchstart", function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   console.log("Tag: " + e.target);
   console.log("Tag Name: " + e.target.tagName);
});
```

The response is.

```
Tag: [object HTMLElement]
Tag Name: I
```

Why? Shouldn't it be anchor?

**UPDATED**

```
$("a, a *").bind(function() {
    e.stopPropagation();

    // other stuff
});
```

Will this do the trick?

Comment: Why not try `<a class="some-bg" href="#">` instead?

Comment: Remember that `i`, `b` and `u` doesn't means much about your semantics. [There are better ways](http://www.impressivewebs.com/bold-italic-html5/)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why?

Because you touched the `<i>` (and then the event bubbled up to the `<a>`).

> Shouldn't it be anchor?

No. Use `currentTarget` if you want the element to which the event is bound rather then the one which actually triggered the event.

Comment: would it happen like I touch "i" and the event gets fired twice?

Comment: The event fires one. It occurs on the `<i>` then bubbles up until it reaches the `<a>` which has an event handler for it. That event handler gets fired. Since you don't `stopPropagation`, it will keep bubbling until it hits an event handler that does or it goes past the root element.

Comment: hey I just realized the problem. The problem is because "i" is indide the "a" and also most of the button space is by the background image of "i" so when I try to touch the button and if my finger is just over the image and not the text, the handler doesn't get fired. How can I rectify this?

Comment: @Umair Ashraf — Umm, you do what I said yesterday in the last paragraph of my original answer.

Comment: Can I make it like handle the event on either "a" or any of its child elements but it just once and not multiple times?

Comment: What I can think of is. Put handler on "a" and on every child of it then inside the handler function e.stopPropagation will do the trick. Am I right here?